# Continuously monitoring a folder to upload newly created files from that folder to REST API in C#

Tags: c#, rest, api, file, upload

I've been searching and reading around to that and couldn't find anything really useful.

I'm writing a small C# win app that allows me to send files to a web server, not by FTP, but by HTTP using POST. Think of it as a web form but running on a windows application continuously monitoring a folder for new files, so it can push it to a REST API.

I will be glad if you can help me out.

I have referred the code.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri(fileUploadUrl), "POST"))
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search for FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Yup, I have to use that API, but I don't know, how to auto upload files from a folder with FileSystemWatcher. I have referred this article here http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/file-upload-using-multipartformdatastreamprovider-in-asp-net-webapi/.
But they are not explaining what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the official docs that ought to do the trick.

It's not that simple though. You need to think about what happens in edge cases (and they are a lot). Top of my head, what happens when a directory is created and then a file in it, which is called 1.txt which already exists in the parent folder.

> -- 1.txt
>
> -- NewFolder
>
> --- 1.txt

```
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        watcher.Path = "C:\WhateverForlderIWantToMonitor";

        // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
        // the renaming of files or directories.
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        // Watch every file
        watcher.Filter = "*";

        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Created += OnCreated;

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Wait for the user to quit the program.
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }


   // Define the event handlers.
   private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            using (Strea mfileStream = File.OpenRead(e.FullPath))
            using (Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri(fileUploadUrl), "POST"))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            }
        }
   }
```